# TypeError in a simple random walk model--Python

Tags: python, typeerror

I've been learning python by watching MIT open courses, and after lecture 17 about random walk simulation model, I wrote a simple piece of code, but it didn't work, and showed an error like this: "TypeError: 'drunk' object is not callable". Hope someone can help me find out where is wrong.

```
from math import*
import random,pylab

    class location(object):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def move(self,xc,yc):
        return location(self.x+float(xc),self.y+float(yc))
    def getCoordinates(self):
        return self.x,self.y
    def getDistance(self,other):
        ox,oy=other.getCoordinates()
        x=fabs(other.x-self.x)
        y=fabs(other.y-self.y)
        return sqrt(x**2+y**2)


class compasspt(object):

    possibles=('n','s','e','w')
    def __init__(self,pt):
        if pt in self.possibles:
            self.pt=pt
        else:
            raise ValueError
    def move(self,dist):
        if self.pt=='n':return (0,dist)
        elif self.pt=='s':return (0,-dist)
        elif self.pt=='w':return (dist,0)
        elif self.pt=='e':return (-dist,0)
        else:raise ValueError


class field(object):

    def __init__(self,drunk,location):
        self.drunk=drunk
        self.location=location
    def move(self,cp,dist):
        oldLocation=self.location
        xc,yc=cp.move(dist) # shadowing
        self.location=oldLocation.move(xc,yc)
    def getLocation(self):
        return self.location
    def getDrunk(self):
        return self.drunk


class drunk(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def move(self,field,time=1):
        if field.getDrunk()!=self:
            raise ValueError('the drunk is not in the field.')
        for i in range(time):
            pt=compasspt(random.choice(compasspt.possibles)) # random walk
            field.move(pt,1)    # shadowing


def performTrial(time,f):
    start=f.getLocation()
    distances=[0.0]
    for t in range(1,time+1):
        f.getDrunk().move(f)
        newLocation=f.getLocation()
        distance=newLocation.getDistance(start)
        distances.append(distance)
    return distances


drunk=drunk('Alexander')
for i in range(3):
    f=field(drunk,location(0,0))
    distances=performTrial(1000,f)
    pylab.plot(distances)
pylab.title('Alexander\'s random walk')
pylab.xlabel('Time')
pylab.ylabel('Distance from Origin')


def performSimulation(time, numTrials):
    distLists=[]
    for trial in range(numTrials):
        d = drunk('Drunk'+str(trial))
        f=field(d,location(0,0))
        distances=performTrial(time,f)
        distLists.append(distances)
    return distLists


def ansQuest(maxTime,numTrials):
    means=[]
    distLists=performSimulation(maxTime,numTrials)
    for t in range(maxTime+1):
        tot=0.0
        for distL in distLists:
            tot+=distL[t]
        means.append(tot/len(distL))
    pylab.figure()
    pylab.plot(means)
    pylab.ylabel('distance')
    pylab.xlabel('time')
    pylab.title('Average Distance vs. Time('+str(len(distLists))+'trials)')

ansQuest(1000,300)
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem comes from using drunk for both the class name and the instance name... Try changing your class to Drunk and then

```
drunk=Drunk('Alexander')
```

and...

```
d = Drunk('Drunk'+str(trial))
```

I don't have pylab installed so I deleted all those lines and it ran clean (albeit without output)

I'm studying Python with o'Reilly and am actually trying to answer questions as part of an assignment so I hope this help you.

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. do you mind if I show this to my instructor? Also, how are you finding the MIT class? Is it complex or fairly easy?

Comment: It's okay. Those classes are broad in contents but not hard to learn. Quite fine for beginners I think.